# Setting Display position of column in DataGrid

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I'm generating a Hyperlink button in the code behind. Problem is the column appears first in the datagrid despite setting the property to `DisplayIndex=4` the column appears first and then the rest of the columns. How can I fix the order of this column?

**XAML Code**

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="163" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="380" Margin="10,59,0,0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Name="ProductGrid"  Visibility="Collapsed">
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Hyperlink">
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:Name="gridTemplate">

                         <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center"  >
                        <HyperlinkButton Content="Hyperlinkbutton" Tag="Hyperlinkbutton" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

**Code behind**

```
private void ProductGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
  DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
  templateColumn.DisplayIndex = 4;
  templateColumn.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["gridTemplate"];
  ProductGrid.Columns.Add(templateColumn);      
}
```

Comment: Why do you set the `DisplayIndex` in your code and not in the markup?

Comment: How can I set it in the markup?

Comment: If I try to set it in the markup I get error `The property DisplayIndex was not found on HyperlinkButton`

Comment: You want the column to appear at index number 4... [MSDN link to documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.displayindex(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: I added the property to `<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Hyperlink" DisplayIndex="4">` but got a very weird error `DisplayIndex must be greater than or equal to 0 and less than 1`

Comment: I see! Sounds like the `DataGrid` tries to apply the index before the autoGenerated columns are added and goes full retard. Well that means we have to set the index only after the columns are generated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a new column, does setting the `DisplayIndex` of your existing column change its position?

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Key="HyperlinkColumn" Header="Hyperlink">
```

and code

```
private void ProductGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender,
    DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    var column = (DataGridColumn) Resources["HyperlinkColumn"];
    column.DisplayIndex = 4;
}
```